# "No Security header in message but required by policy" al intentar consumir web services

Tags: c#, wcf

Estoy intentando consumir unos web services y me da permanentemente el error

> "No Security header in message but required by policy."

¿Qué debo añadir en la llamada?

Este es el WSDL: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

y este es el mi código:

```
try
{
  // la url del servicio
  string urlServicio = @"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

  var address = new EndpointAddress(urlServicio);
  // creamos la seguridas del transporte
  var binding = new BasicHttpsBinding();
  binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
  // creamos el servico que vamos a mandar
  var client = new servicioGenCATTTAImport.JwsClient(binding, address);

  // añadimos al servicio el certificado (la seguridad)
  client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
    StoreLocation.CurrentUser,
    StoreName.My,
    X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber,
    conexionObject.idCertificadoEmpresa
  );
  var taulaMaestra = new servicioGenCATTTAImport.ttaconsultaTaulaMestra();
  taulaMaestra.dadesTME = new servicioGenCATTTAImport.ttaconsultaTaulaMestraDadesTME();
  taulaMaestra.dadesTME.idiomaTME = "ESP";
  taulaMaestra.dadesTME.codiTME = "TIPUS_DOCUMENT_ESCRIT";

  taulaMaestra.dadesAplicacio = new servicioGenCATTTAImport.ttaconsultaTaulaMestraDadesAplicacio();
  var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\angel\OneDrive\Escritorio\certificados\certificadoED.pfx");
  taulaMaestra.dadesAplicacio.CDA = bytes;
  taulaMaestra.dadesAplicacio.descClient = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  taulaMaestra.dadesAplicacio.codiClient = "XXXXXXX";

  // llamamos al servicio
  var kk = client.consultaTME(taulaMaestra);

  return conexionObject;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  return conexionObject;
}
```

He probado añadiendo el certificado en formato PFX, .CER (binario y B64) y nada, he intentado pedir soporte al organismo oficial que lo gestiona y me contestan que esto está fuera de su alcance.

Al parecer desde JAVA, funciona perfectamente, pero yo desconozco JAVA y necesito que vaya en core .NET.

Comment: Usa la propiedad ClientCredentials.UserName. para definir el usuario y el password que es requerido para realizar la petición.

Answer (score 0):

Desconozco c#, pero viendo tu código no veo que incluyas algún header en la petición. Siendo soap, es posible que necesites, dentro de `taulaMaestra` un nivel header, que contenga los valores que el servidor espera.

En teoría deberían pasarte algún manual de cómo hacer la petición si tiene security. No te viene nada relativo a headers?

edito: En el enlace que compartes, se puede ver para el servicio `ConsultaTME` el siguiente request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:open="http://www.openuri.org/" xmlns:xb="http://xmlbeans.tta.justicia.gencat.cat">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <open:consultaTME>
         <xb:ttaconsultaTaulaMestra>
            <xb:dadesAplicacio>
               <xb:codiClient>?</xb:codiClient>
               <xb:descClient>?</xb:descClient>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <xb:CDA>cid:189135672817</xb:CDA>
            </xb:dadesAplicacio>
            <xb:dadesTME>
               <xb:codiTME>?</xb:codiTME>
               <xb:idiomaTME>?</xb:idiomaTME>
            </xb:dadesTME>
         </xb:ttaconsultaTaulaMestra>
      </open:consultaTME>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

como puedes ver, hay un Header y un Body. Por el error entiendo que No rellenas el dato "header".

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, pero en el onjeto taulaMaestra no se pueden añadir headers, o yo al menos no se como hacerlo. Muchas gracias.

Comment: por lo que estoy viendo seria mas a nivel de client. ConsultaTME contiene taulaMestra, por lo que seguramente va en el body. Has probado a mirar en client.header (si es que existe)? Edito mi respuesta pra añadirte el xml de peticion que tiene el ConsultaTME

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje:

> "No Security header in message but required by policy."

Indica generalmente que requieres un Username y Password válido (Username Token)

Definelo en tu servicio:

```
...
...
 var client = new servicioGenCATTTAImport.JwsClient(binding, address);

  // añadimos al servicio el certificado (la seguridad)
  client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
    StoreLocation.CurrentUser,
    StoreName.My,
    X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber,
    conexionObject.idCertificadoEmpresa
  );

 client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "usuario";
 client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";
 ...
 ...
```

Revisa [Propiedad ClientCredentials.UserName .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.description.clientcredentials.username?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=netcore-3.1)